# How to force/change/specify the WSL 2 network interface

Tags: networking

I have a problem with WSL2 (Ubuntu) and I don't know how to patch it.
When I start wsl after a reboot, a WSL network interface is created.
It's always the same one :

```
Carte Ethernet vEthernet (WSL) :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 172.24.128.1
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . :
```

So my Ubuntu got the current configuration :

```
> ip a show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:7c:02:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.24.131.119/20 brd 172.24.143.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe7c:295/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

> ip route
default via 172.24.128.1 dev eth0 proto kernel
172.24.128.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.24.131.119
```

All the network is OK, I can reach internet and intranet machines BUT we have machines on 172.24.136.0/24 which is a I understand in conflict with 172.24.128.0/20 "virtual" subnet...
So when I want to connect to this VM, I have a "no route to host" error.

```
> ssh 172.24.136.13
ssh: connect to host 172.24.136.13 port 22: No route to host

> traceroute 172.24.136.13
traceroute to 172.24.136.13 (172.24.136.13), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.24.131.119 (172.24.131.119)  3136.309 ms !H  3136.272 ms !H  3136.267 ms !H
```

Any idea ? It's making me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to https://github.com/jgregmac/hyperv-fix-for-devs I should be able to force the WSL network to a custom value :)

Comment: While the link you provided may answer the question, it's better to include the instructions, or at least a summary, directly in your answer.  Link-only answers are [strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413510/11810933), and often even deleted by Moderators on Stack Exchange sites since [they aren't considered complete "answers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).  Thanks!

Comment: Well, this link is a tool that create the WSL network before WSL start with the network range you want.
With this powershell scripts I fix my WSL network to the default network 192.168.100.0/24

Comment: Please add some details to the answer. While it's to link software, it's not ok to just send 1 sentence without any sort of instruction as to how to achieve the goal with that software. E.g, include config changes that need to be made